# Web API extend List with additional properties

Tags: list, generics, asp.net-web-api

I like to extend a list of items with additional properties on list level.
So I can give the name of the List, Paging information, etc.

This is the sample object item for the list:

```
public class House
{
    public int Nummer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Simple List class - with one additional property:

```
public class SimpleList : List<House>
{
  public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Web Api Controller Method:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public SimpleList Get()
    {
        SimpleList houseList = new SimpleList {};
        houseList.Add(new House { Name = "Name of House", Nummer = 1 });
        houseList.Add(new House { Name = "Name of House", Nummer = 2 });
        houseList.MyExtraProperty = "MyExtraProperty value";

        return houseList;
    }
}
```

The result shows in XML:

```
<ArrayOfHouse>
 <House><Name>Name of House</Name><Nummer>1</Nummer></House>
 <House><Name>Name of House</Name><Nummer>2</Nummer></House>
</ArrayOfHouse>
```

And in Json
[{"Nummer":1,"Name":"Name of House"},{"Nummer":2,"Name":"Name of House"}]

My question is **how can I get MyExtraProperty parsed** to the result?

my mini demo solution to play around is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/638054/permanent/WebApiGenerics.zip

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to let your List be a member not a superclass of SimpleList

```
public class SimpleList 
{
    public List<House> Houses;
    public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
}
```

If you just need JSON you could control serialization yourself by decorating the model for Newtonsoft JSON:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApiGenerics.Models
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class SimpleList : List<House>
    {
        [JsonProperty]
        public IEnumerable<House> Houses
        {
            get { return this.Select(x => x); }
        }

        [JsonProperty]
        public string MyExtraProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```